# Substring Respond from GPRS Arduino AT Command

Tags: arduino, substring, at-command

I'm using Module sim 900 (V.1),
When I write "AT+CCLK?" there have a respond is ;
"2014/04/11 ; 07:02:08 +28"
and then I just want to take "07:02:28" only for write this to sd card..
Anyone here can help me take these one ?

```
void loop() {
        Serial.println("Loop Starts");
        delay(5000);
        gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT");
        delay(5000);
        gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
        gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CSQ");
        delay(5000);
        gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
        gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CLTS=1");
        delay(5000);
        gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
        gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CCLK?");
        delay(5000);
        gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
        gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CREG?");
        delay(5000);
        gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have used.

Comment: Here the void loop

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("Loop Starts");
  delay(5000);

  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT");
  delay(5000);
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();

  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CSQ");
  delay(5000);
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
  
  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CLTS=1");
  delay(5000);
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
  
  
  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CCLK?");
  delay(5000);
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
  
  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CREG?");
  delay(5000);
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();